# data sent through a pipe from parent to child

Tags: c, child-process

I wrote a program that uses a `pipe` to send messages from a parent to a child.

Question: Is this the correct way I sent the messages? Could I have done otherwise? What can I improve?

my code:

```
//Parent/child processes communicating via a pipe
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    int f_des[2];
    static char message[BUFSIZ];
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            printf("Usage: %s", * argv);
            printf(" message\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        if (pipe(f_des) == -1)
        {
            perror("Pipe");
            return 2;
        }
        switch (fork())
        {
        case -1:
            perror("Fork");
            return 3;
        case 0:
            close(f_des[1]);
        if (read(f_des[0], message, BUFSIZ) != -1)
        {
            printf("Message received by child: %s\n", message);
            fflush(stdout);
        } 
        else
        {
            perror("Read");
            return 4;
        }
        break;
        default:
            close(f_des[0]);
            if (write(f_des[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) != -1)
            {
                printf("Message sent by parent : %s\n", argv[1]);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
            else
            {
                perror("Write");
                return 5;
            }
         }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're really keen to get to grips with this stuff, I'd suggest getting your hands on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment - the book's a little long in the tooth now, but as far as I know the information hasn't been superceded. W Richard Stevens covers process control and interprocess communication in great detail and with great clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Error messages should go to the standard error stream:

```
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s message\n", *argv);
        return 1;
```

No need to flush any standard stream here, as returning from `main()` does that as part of exiting the program.

---

In the child side, we throw away the return value of `read()` after we compare with -1.  However, we need to use that value in order to print only the number of characters actually written (since the parent didn't write a null character to the stream).  So we need something like

```
    int len = read(f_des[0], message, BUFSIZ);
    if (len < 0)
    {
        perror("Read");
        return 4;
    }
    printf("Message received by child: %.*s\n", len, message);
```